# HTML Form WebPart as filter with multiple connections and empty fields

Tags: multiple-values, web-part-connection, html-form-web-part

I've got a HTML form WebPart that has multiple connections (Done in SPD) to the adjacent WebPart displaying a document library. It's 3 select boxes, and provided you select an option for all of them, it works fine. If the value is empty when filtering with another select box, it still passes on that value to the document library filter and filters accordingly, showing nothing.

So how do I set this form to NOT provide filter data for that field when nothing is selected? I've tried `value=""` I've tried `value="*"` as some kind of wild card option, I've tried no value parameter at all, but it still passes on the empty value regardless.